# Export a Date to Excel using jasper

Tags: date, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm starting to work with Jasper and havea little problem. I want to export a date who is in my DB and export it to excel and save the date format. The Date is saved with Date in the DB.

The error was when i open the excel file with the data exported the date is not with format date but General. But show right with the pattern written in the **jrxml**.

[image]

That's the code I use to excel export. The other part of the jrxml i think is the default one.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true" hyperlinkType="None">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="343" y="0" width="68" height="21"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="true" pdfFontName="arial.ttf"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[$F{Date1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong ???

*Another, little question:*
- In my Eclipse project i use the jasperreports.jar version 3.5 but i handle/modify the .jrxml with iReporter 3.1.1. That's could cause the problem or problems for use different versions ??

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `Date1` field?

Comment: You can use [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type) report's property. And you can set format for the cell with [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern***](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern) property

Comment: For more details you can read this posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003339/excel-cell-format-in-jasperreport-report & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714709/jasperreports-how-to-format-numeric-data-with-excel-exporter

Answer (score 2):

Refer : http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures

> Format patterns are useful when data have to be presented in a
>   completely readable and meaningful form. To see an example, dates are
>   often stored as numbers (the number of milliseconds that have passed
>   since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT). But reading such kind of
>   numbers does not fit our usual representation of a date, with
>   perfectly delimited year, month and day fields. A format pattern is
>   absolutely necessary here, to get a meaningful representation of these
>   numbers. Here comes the pattern attribute of textfields to solve the
>   problem. For almost all output formats, excepting the Excel ones.
>   That's because the pattern attribute contains standard Java format
>   patterns. Unfortunately, not all patterns valid for Java are valid for
>   Excel too. There are situations where such a pattern should be
>   translated in order to be recognized in Excel. An older way to realize
>   this translation is to use the getFormatPatternsMap() exporter setting
>   at runtime, with the same inconvenient as shown in the Dynamic Sheet
>   Names section: the need of Java hardcoding. Instead of this, now one
>   has the possibility to specify the proper format pattern for Excel
>   right in the report sample, at element level, using the custom
>   property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern To see it in action,
>   take a look at the current date textfield in the
>   XlsFeaturesReport.jrxml sample's  section:
>
> ```
> <textField pattern="EEE, MMM d, yyyy">
>   <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="30" width="515" height="30" forecolor="#000000">
>     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="ddd, mmm d, yyyy"/>
>   </reportElement>
>   ...
>   </textField>
> ```
>
> In this case the EEE, MMM d, yyyy pattern, completely valid in Java
>   but generating unreadable content for Excel, is replaced with the
>   equivalent ddd, mmm d, yyyy pattern when exporting report to Excel.