# Sum time column in Excel 2010 after exporting the report to Excel

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I have application which exports JR report to *Excel 2010* sheet, well its exports successfully but the problem is with time column.

Now my requirement is to sum up the time column to gets the total time spend, so the time column gets displayed as follows:

```
Time

11.46.10

12.21.11

14.43.54

14.45.07

10.09.13
```

Now when I click on the time cell say 11.46.10 at the top the function bar displays 1/1/1970  11.46.10 AM so this date 1/1/1970 which automatically gets appended is creating problem so now I manually remove the date i.e. 1/1/1970 from the cell and try summing up the column by the SUM(C1:C20) function its gives me correct result.

The problem is with date 1/1/1970 which automatically gets appended, now how it gets appended is the question

I have also attached the code snippet of that particular column which is having class type as ***java.sql.Time*** and I am sure we are not using anywhere this date 1/1/1970 or appending it.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you manually change the cells format?

Comment: Nope Alex the format of the cell is of Time (I don't change the cell format manually) having pattern hh.mm.ss no problem with that question is about why this date gets appended before time

Comment: In my case (for ***java.sql.Timestamp*** field) the value appears in cell (Excel) without any date (1/1/1970). I've used the pattern like you. My *iReport* (I've tested report in this designer) version is 4.5.1.

Comment: Again java.sql.Timestamp field will require date value along with time and our column is of completely time not date ? As doing this I get the error while I generate the report saying the data is not in format i.e. DD.MM.YY hh.mm.ss some thing like that

Comment: What is the type of ***$F{ACTVTIME}*** field?

Comment: Its of java.sql.Time type and from DB we get the value in this format 11:46:10 which represents hh.mm.ss

Comment: I've just tried the ***java.sql.Time*** type of field - and it is displays ok (without date).

Comment: You can try to set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*** property for the *textField* and ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type*** report's property as **true**

Comment: I had tried out setting 
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true" />
at reports property level but can i know how can i set  net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern property for the textField ?
sorry for not being much expert in jasper report

Comment: You can look at [this my sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9065217/876298)

Comment: Thanks Alex let me try out doing this may be it will take 20 mins or so

Comment: All unspecified-date times in excel (and pretty much all programs) are assigned some arbitrary date. In excel it is 01/01/1900. Perhaps in your java program it is using 01/01/1970. If you explicity tell the program by typing in a cell "12:46:10 12/10/85" it will use that date and time - but otherwise it assumes that arbitrary date and time. But to get the "time spent" you just need to subtract your arbitrary time from the beginning of your arbitrary day.

Comment: Alex i had tried adding net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern in textField but no change